# What is k variable on antenna theory

Tags: antenna

**I make my text on bold so it distinguishes from the print-screens I post.**

**I am reading Antenna theory Analysis and Design, Balanis (Wiley 2016).
At page 17, (subsection 1.4 CURRENT DISTRIBUTION ON A THIN WIRE ANTENNA), I see \$sin(kl/2)\$, where \$k\$ is not explained. Is it a positive integer? aka \$k=0,1,2,...\$, or a specific variable for antennas?**

[image: Balanis antenna theory]

**I tried to ctrl+f the pdf, and the \$k\$ does not seem to be explained later on. The next time it appears on the book is page 38, subsection 2.4 RADIATION INTENSITY, where it talks about far-zone electric-field intensity of the antenna. But is it the same \$k\$ as before? It does not explain this one either.**

[image: far-zone electric-field intensity of the antenna]

**Also at section 6.2 and below I observe the usage of multiplying it with d: \$kd\$**. Where k is again, not explained. is it the same variable?

[image: total field radiated]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the *[wavenumber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber)* \$k\$; should be introduced pretty early in a chapter about wave theory / how the existence of propagating waves arises from Maxwell!

It's really just what you highlight in the first line of (6-3): the factor in the complex part of the exponent of your E-field exp. That's actually its significance!

Comment: Thanks! I ctrl+f it, Its actually mentioned at page 708 (so not early at all). I guess its considered already known knowledge

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios ah, OK. Yeah, in a book on antenna design, I guess that's expected. I should have checked my own Balanis!